# Cant get path to a string using Poco

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I'm trying to put the path in a string, but it always empty:

```
Poco::URI uri("http://10.10.10.10:3535");
std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
```

This string part never receive anything and stays empty..
The code snippet is taking from an example https://gist.github.com/FatalCatharsis/749d93b4592e7d59d91a

Comment: What do you get when URI is `http://10.10.10.10:3535/path/page.html?q=query` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your URI the Path and Query are empty, so it is correct that you see an empty string. Your URI only has a Scheme, Host and Port.

Here is a diagram of the URI format from Wikipedia:

```
                    authority               path
        ┌───────────────┴───────────────┐┌───┴────┐
  abc://username:password@example.com:123/path/data?key=value#fragid1
  └┬┘   └───────┬───────┘ └────┬────┘ └┬┘           └───┬───┘ └──┬──┘
scheme  user information     host     port            query   fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

`http://10.10.10.10:3535` does not have any path or query in the string, that is why it is empty.
Here is you can separate URI :

```
scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]
eg. http:://192.168.11.2:3000/user?action=edit#basic
```